# mongodb replicaset auto sync config file with a new member

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a replica set with 2 machines: Machine 1 et machine 2.

When I start a new mongod.exe in a third machine. How can I tell it to sync his replica set config file from machine 1 or machine 2 ?

Here's what I tried:

```
mongod.exe --dbpath d:\mongo\3 --port 27003 --replSet abc/machine1:27001,machine2:27002
```

But it doesn't work. It says:
replSet can't get local.system.replset config from self or any seed (EMPTYCONFIG)

What I don't want to do, is to connect to machine 1 and add the third machine: rs.Add("machine3:27003")

Answer (score 0):

To reconfigure a replica set you **must** connect to the current primary (i.e. `Member 1`, from your description). Adding or removing a replica set member increments the version of the [replica set config](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/replica-configuration/) which then needs to be propagated to all current members of the replica set.

If you have a recent backup or snapshot of an existing replica set member you can copy the data files to a new member in order to potentially expedite the initial sync process. In particular, copying existing data files avoids rebuilding all the indexes but also copies over preallocated storage space (rather than just the data). However, any replica set reconfiguration still has to be done by connecting to the current primary.

For more information see the full tutorial in the MongoDB documentation: [Add Members to a Replica Set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/).